# How to set correctly parameters to batch file to run "git pull"?

Tags: git, bash, batch-file, batch-processing, git-pull

I have following code in my .bat file:

```
cd C:\\TESTS\pathToFolderWhereIWantToGitPull
start "path to git bash.exe" git pull
pause
```

Git bash open correctly but bash.exe close very fast and dont do a git pull in that folder. What I am doing wrong here? The bash.exe is correct application to do git pull? Any ideas what to do to run this code correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried earlier by cmd commands but I had access denied. Now I found solution in basic cmd:

```
cd c://TESTS/path
set HOME=%USERPROFILE%
git pull 
pause
```

I missed a HOME variable. Now it is working without using git.exe or bash.exe.

Answer (score 1):

The start command will launch a new application in a separate window, and then the window will close as soon as the application ends. You really shouldn't need to launch bash.exe to run git. You can just run `git pull` in place of your start command and that should work. You may need to give the full path to git.exe. You also may not need the pause any more, depending on whether you are running this from an existing command prompt, or just double-clicking a shortcut.

```
cd C:\Tests\path
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe" pull
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

put this code in to your .bat file

```
cd c://TESTS/path
set HOME=%USERPROFILE%
git pull 
pause
```